# Problems while installing chatterbot via Pip

Tags: python, pip, chatterbot

I've been trying to install chatterbot with pip but when i did

```
pip install ChatterBot
```

it gave me this error:

```
 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: legacy-install-failure

      Encountered error while trying to install package.

      preshed

      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for output from the failure.
      [end of output]
```

Comment: Do you get anything else? Maybe an error message? This is just a note.
Also, have you tried running `pip install --upgrade pip` to see if your `pip` version is outdated?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say from what you've posted but for me it was that I used python 3.10. ChatterBot only works up to python 3.8 (see info in release 1.0.7 here: https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/releases).
So check what version of python you have installed. If it's higher than 3.8 it might be the problem.

Comment: You're correct most of the issue coming with installation are due to python versions >3.8, Idk why they plan to release for version>3.8

Answer (score 0):

Could you try installing a specific version:

```
pip install chatterbot==1.0.2
```

or

```
pip install chatterbot==1.0.4
```

Change the version as needed.